# Linking file geodatabase and ArcSDE?

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, arcgis-online, file-geodatabase, database

My office does a lot of field work where we log points via the Collector app. Those points are then always exported to a geodatabase feature class for further editing and analysis. If edits and changes are made to the feature class, we then have to go back and re-publish the file to the server so that everything matches and the file is up to date in both places. Is there a way to just link the two so that when changes are made to one, changes are automatically made to the other?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please be sure to take the [Tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour). It's not automatic, but [child-to-parent one-way replication](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.2/index.html#//003n000000t6000000) does a lot of what you're describing. If you need specific help, please edit the question to contain the version of ArcGIS in use and details about what you've tried.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You mention you are using a server, are you using ArcSDE?  if so then you want to set up versioning with your parent being your main GDB and the child being what your crews are editing on in the field.  That would allow you to edit in multiple sessions and they are all reconciled against the parent version.  Changes made on any field copy will be automatically linked to the parent. Here is an overview and guide to how to set them up.

http://www.esri.com/news/arcuser/0110/versioning101.html

http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.1/index.html#//003n000000t7000000